# Django , upload multiple images with formset's

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I've been trying for days to understand the reason for my error, in the first phase I detected that it was missing  **{{ formset.management_form }}** in the html, which  i include and still continues to give the same error:

```
"ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with"
```

And I don't know if my *views* are the way they should be done.

**Models**

```js
class Intervencao(models.Model):
      ........
      
      
class Imagem(models.Model):
        intervencao = models.ForeignKey(Intervencao, related_name='intervencaoObjectsImagem', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Fotografia")

        def __str__(self, ):
            return str(self.intervencao)

<!-- e
```

**Forms**

```js
class TabletForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Intervencao
        fields = __all__
      
class TabletFormImagem(forms.ModelForm):
    imagem = forms.ImageField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Imagem
        fields = ['imagem',]
```

**Views**

```js
def project_detail_chefe(request, pk):
    ImagemFormSet = modelformset_factory(Imagem,form=TabletFormImagem, extra=3)
    instance = Intervencao.objects.get(id=pk)
    d1 = datetime.now()
    intervencaoForm = TabletForm2(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    formset = ImagemFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,queryset=Imagem.objects.none())
       if request.method == "POST":
           if intervencaoForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
              instance_form1 = intervencaoForm.save(commit=False)
              instance_form1.data_intervencao_fim = d1
              instance_form1.save()
              images = formset.save(commit=False)
              for image in images:
                  image.intervencao = instance_form1
                  image.save()
                return redirect('index')
            else:   
                intervencaoForm = TabletForm2(request.POST)
                formset = ImagemFormSet(queryset=Imagem.objects.none())
      context = {
          'intervencaoForm':intervencaoForm,
          'formset':formset,
      }
      return render(request, 'tablet/info_chefes.html', context)
```

**HTML**

```js
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gravar">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
                {{ formset.management_form }}
                {% for form in formset %}
                    {{ form }}
                {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case , the problem was the

```js
else:   
                intervencaoForm = TabletForm2(request.POST)
                formset = ImagemFormSet(queryset=Imagem.objects.none())
```

beacause is in line with the wrong `if`. all working now